# ComboBox Multiple Option Values In HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

Is it possible to do it some kind of option value with three possibilities?

Like this:

```
<select id="State">
<option value="val1" || "val2" || "val3">Title</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give us your use case. I didn't find your post about much details about your question.

Comment: Problem solved otherwise, but really thanks for commitment!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for? Your post isn't as detailed as it could be :)

```
<select id="State">
<option value="val1">Title1</option>
<option value="val2">Title2</option>
<option value="val3">Title3</option>
</select>
```